# angularjs : calling a function in select element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to call a function in the case given below?

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option ng-repeat="group in myGroups" ng-model="group.Name" ng-change="myFunction(group.Id)">{{group.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

- ng-click won't work
- ng-model is needed if you want to use ng-change (I don't need ng-model in this case otherwise)
- ng-change doesn't seem to call a function as well
- I know I could probably just use ng-model and $watch, but since I don't think I can really use ng-model in this case I am a bit confused

So, how can I call a function inside ng-repeat select? (its not ng-select as you probably noticed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the `option` itself does not change.

What changes is the value of the `select` element.

So, try this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedGroup" ng-change="yourFunction()">
   <option ng-repeat="group in myGroups">{{group.name}}</option>
</select>
```

with a `yourFunction` on the current `scope`like this:

```
scope.yourFunction = function() {
   console.log(scope.selectedGroup);
};
```

I also strongly suggest you have a look at `ngOptions` [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Comment: Thanks, I was somehow reluctant to ngOptions since it all seemed a bit hard to grasp, but now I see it's handy as it can be. I like that you answered my question directly and also pointed out that ngOptions would probably be a better solution.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YGf7d/2/ is an example of ng-options being used with the ng-model on the select element